# Finding an image tag using the alt text

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, tags

I would like to know if it was possible using Javascript to find an image tag by its alt text. For instance I have this tag: `<img src="Myimage.jpg" alt="Myimage">` would there be a way to obtain the tag by looking for the "Myimage" alt attribute?

Comment: I see you're finding an image tag using the alt text. You should totally drop that and use jQuery!

Comment: The better question is, are you using any JS library? (jquery, prototype, mootols, yui..)

Answer (score 18):

```
var imgElement = document.querySelector('img[alt="MyImage"]')
```

Comment: Correct answer is `var imgElement = document.querySelector('img[alt="MyImage"]')`.
Text inside querySelector needs to be in quotes. If not console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined"

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix said error

Answer (score 15):

There will undoubtedly be a jQuery solution posted soon enough. To do it without, the following will work:

```
function getImagesByAlt(alt) {
    var allImages = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = allImages.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (allImages[i].alt == alt) {
            images.push(allImages[i]);
        }
    }
    return images;
}

var myImage = getImagesByAlt("Myimage")[0];
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com).  The following JQuery code will return any image with the alt tag set to "Myimage":

```
$('img[alt="Myimage"]').
```

However it would be a lot easier and a lot more performant to use the id attribute of the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be so hard if NodeList implemented Iterable. This implementation puts filter into the prototype of NodeList, which may not match everyones taste but I prefer concise access to my data structures.

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // unfortunately NodeLists do not have many of the nice Iterate functions
            // on them, here is an incomplete filter implementation
            NodeList.prototype.filter = function(testFn) {
                var array = [] ;
                for (var cnt = 0 ; cnt < this.length ; cnt++) {
                    if (testFn(this[cnt])) array.push(this[cnt]) ; 
                }
                return array ;
            }

            // loops through the img tags and finds returns true for elements that
            // match the alt text
            function findByAlt(altText) {
                var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img').filter(function(x) {
                    return x.alt === altText ;
                }) ;

                return imgs ;

            }

            // start the whole thing
            function load() {
                var images = findByAlt('sometext') ;

                images.forEach(function(x) {
                    alert(x.alt) ;
                }) ;
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="load()">
        <img src="./img1.png" alt="sometext"/>
        <img src="./img2.png" alt="sometext"/>
        <img src="./img3.png" alt="someothertext"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note you'll get an array back since there is nothing in the DOM spec about having unique alt tags.

Comment: Unfortunately the extension of `NodeList` rules out IE (at least up to and including version 7, I don't have 8 to hand to test).

Comment: Ah, luckily/unfortunately I operate in a world without IE. What does IE present as the return of getElementsByTagName?

Comment: I believe that it is a `NodeList` of sorts, but there's no direct access to a `NodeList` constructor function.

Comment: Ah right, well thanks for that :) /me goes to read the jquery source