# random image coding js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

so i made a bot for discord and i want it to show a random image when i type g!guess. so i made it work with

```
if (message.content === 'g!guess') {
        number = 2;
        imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        message.channel.send ( {files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".png"]} )  
    }
```

it shows a random image, i actually have only 2 images named 1.png and 2.png.

I'd like to make that when a random image is shows if i type its name i get a message, like i have 2 images a space image and a dog, if the dog image appear and i write 'dog' i get a message, and if i type something else nothing happen, if i write g!guess and the space image appear, if i write 'space' i get the message. I'd like it to show an image and that i have like 20 second to guess the name of it, and when the time finish it show a message like 'Time's out'. I hope its understandable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to inform the code that 1.png is a dog image whereas 2.png is a space image. It would be easier to guide you with a copy of the code but here's a high-level walkthrough:

I would go about this by adding an alt tag to each image and reference it in the javascript function.

for example:
`<img src="src/to/img.png" alt="dog"/>`

Here's how to reference the alt tag using javascript: [Finding An image tag using the alt text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914456/finding-an-image-tag-using-the-alt-text)

hth.

Comment: nah i want that when a random image appear after i typed g!guess, that if i type its name in 20 second i get an answer if the name i wrote is right. like i type g!guess and a dog image appear, if i type "dog" in 20 second the bot answer with a message, if i write something else thats not "dog" nothing happen